# How do I declare a two dimensional dynamic array inside of a Class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I have a class that needs to have a two dimensional array that I can initialize during construction by passing it two parameters. How do you declare a two-dimensional dynamic array within a class.

```
class Life
{
public:
    Life (int rows, int cols);
    ~Life ();
    Life(const Life& orig);
    Life& operator=(const Life& rhs);

    void init();
    void print();
    void update();
    void instructions();
    bool user_says_yes();
private:
    int rows;
    int cols;

    int neighbor_count(int row, int col);
    int** grid;
};

Life::Life(int row, int col)
{
    rows = row;
    cols = col;
    grid = new [rows][cols];
}
```

I know there's something wrong with the array because in the constructor it says that it should be a constant value. But I will not know the value until the user enters the values. But somehow I need to have an array in this class that will be dynamically created to a specified size. For now I can not use vectors, but if you know how to make it work with vectors it might help others.

Comment: @Kal Oh wow, that's like, super useful, especially after OP clearly said he knows about vectors but can't use them for now!

Comment: Do have to use `new`? can't just do: `int grid[N][M];`?

Comment: @billz, no C++ doesn't work like that.

Comment: @MarkRansom yeah, if he needs to dynamic rows/cols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do that like this:

```
grid=new int*[rows];
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
      grid[i]=new int[cols];
}
```

The first line initializes an array which will contain a total of *rows* pointers, and then each of these pointers is allocated to hold a total of *cols* integers.
And in your destructor:

```
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
      delete[] grid[i];
}
delete[] grid;
```

Here you have to deallocate the rows first, because *grid* is storing their addresses, and deleting it first would cause you to lose them.

Keep in mind that if you copy an object of this class, you will need to do this initialization for the copy too. That includes the *=* operator and the copy constructor.

Comment: +1 But OP has to do the same in the copy and assignment operations as well. Also explain a bit what the current code is doing. It would be helpful to any in future than just posting code.

Comment: I've seen this before but finally reading it with your description it makes perfect sense. I'm going to try that. The update function has to declare another two dimensional array to copy everything over from grid so I'll have to do this there too.

Comment: I have to ask, how do I access the data, like if I make a new grid and I want to copy one to the other is it as simple as:

new_grid[i][j] = grid[i][j];

And how do I actually store data in a row, if the array of rows contain pointers to columns. I would like to be able to go to say row 3 column 2 and make the value a 0 or 1. How would I access that specific number?

Comment: To copy, yes, you do that for each row and column (after allocating space). To set the row 3, column 2 to 0, you do grid[3][2]=0, since the first [] gives the row, and the second [] gives you the actual integer.

Comment: Just have to say I have a much deeper understanding of two dimensional dynamic arrays as class data members now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you should use a vector of vectors. But since you cannot...

There are two ways to do a two-dimensional vector. The first is to create a one-dimensional vector and condense the two dimensions into one when you access it. You can put that behind a class method if you want to treat it as 2-D.  `grid = new int[rows*cols]; grid[c*rows+r]`

The second method is to make an array of pointers, where each pointer is a one-dimensional array for a row. You need to allocate all of the row pointers individually.